# Where com data e hora - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou fazendo um select com entity framework. onde eu preciso utilizar o where, com data e hora, no select do SQL SERVER, eu faria desta forma:

```
     select dbo.contas_receber.id, dbo.contas_receber.tipo_conta,dbo.contas_receber.data_pagamento, dbo.contas_receber.data_pagamento,dbo.contas_receber.observacao, dbo.contas_receber.valor,dbo.contas_receber.forma_pagamento from dbo.contas_receber  where (dbo.contas_receber.data_pagamento) >= ('" + data_abertura + "')  and DATEADD(day,  -DATEDIFF(day, 0,'" + data_abertura + "'), dbo.contas_receber.data_pagamento) >= '" + hora_aber + "'
```

No entity, consegui fazer só a parte da data, não consigo fazer a parte da hora:

```
_context.ContasApagar.Select(p => new CaixasViewModel
        {
            Data = p.DataPagamento,
            Hora = p.DataPagamento,
            Historico = p.Obs,
            Valor = p.ValorPago,
            Forma = p.FormaPagamento
        }).ToList()).Where(p => p.Data >= data_abertura && p.Hora >= DateTime.Parse(hora_aber));
```

Se eu faço assim, ele não faz o select correto, ele filtra por data maior que data_abertura, e hora maior que hora_abertura, porém se a hora for menor, mas for um dia pra frente de data_abertura, ele devia aparecer no select.

Comment: o que vem em `data_abertura` e `hora_aber` ? um é datetime outro string ?

Comment: Data abertura é um dateTime, e hora_abert é um string.

Comment: e qual conteúdo dela: `hora_aber` ("01/01/0001 08:10:00" ou "08:10:00"... ) ?

Comment: Hora_aber é 08:10, eu preciso por exemplo, a data abertura é 12/07/2018 15:00, e existe uma conta que foi paga no dia 13/07/2018 10:20, esta conta precisa aparecer, filtrando pela hora não dá certo, pois 10:20 é menor que 15:00, no sql eu utilizo DATEADD(day,  -DATEDIFF(day, 0,'" + data_abertura + "'), no entity não sei como fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo motivo pra separar Data de Hora... no C# o DateTime trata os dois, então se você converter "08:10" pra DateTime, o valor será 01/01/0001 08:10:00.

Você precisa informar a Data também.

Além disso, você pode filtrar os objetos antes do Select, assim filtraria em p.DataPagamento.

```
DateTime hora_abertura = DateTime.Parse(hora_aber);
DateTime data = data_abertura.AddHours(hora_abertura.Hour).AddMinutes(hora_abertura.Minute);


_context.ContasApagar.Where(p=> p.DataPagamento >= data).Select(p => new CaixasViewModel
        {
            Data = p.DataPagamento,
            Hora = p.DataPagamento,
            Historico = p.Obs,
            Valor = p.ValorPago,
            Forma = p.FormaPagamento
        }).ToList();
```

A conversão do DateTime, coloquei no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/738fZg)